# Grouping consecutive hashes from an array by property

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to find groups of n x consecutive appointments from an array of appointments.

my data looks like this:

```
  [{:event_id=>295, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>296, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>297, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>311, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>312, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>313, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>314, :appointment=>396, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>315, :appointment=>397, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>316, :appointment=>398, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>317, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>318, :appointment=>399, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>319, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>320, :appointment=>400, :accounted=>false},
   {:event_id=>321, :appointment=>401, :accounted=>false}]>
```

and I want to be able to find any 3-consecutive appointment groups.  So in this case events 314,315,316 is the only group that should be returned.

To be honest, I'm not even sure where to start...

Comment: What would be returned if event 317 was missing, i.e. if there are more than 3 consecutive appointments?

Comment: just the 1st 3 consecutive still - because im working out which appointments can be paid for by quantity packages

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) to group the array by consecutive appointments:

```
arr = [{:event_id=>295, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>296, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>297, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>311, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>312, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>313, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>314, :appointment=>396, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>315, :appointment=>397, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>316, :appointment=>398, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>317, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>318, :appointment=>399, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>319, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>320, :appointment=>400, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>321, :appointment=>401, :accounted=>false}]

groups = arr.slice_before(appointment: false) { |elt, state|
  a, b = state[:appointment], elt[:appointment] # get previous (a) and current (b) appointment
  state[:appointment] = elt[:appointment]       # update state
  a == false || b == false || a.succ != b       # slicing condition
}

groups.to_a
#=> [[{:event_id=>295, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>296, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>297, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>311, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>312, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>313, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>314, :appointment=>396, :accounted=>false},
#     {:event_id=>315, :appointment=>397, :accounted=>false},
#     {:event_id=>316, :appointment=>398, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>317, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>318, :appointment=>399, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>319, :appointment=>false, :accounted=>false}],
#    [{:event_id=>320, :appointment=>400, :accounted=>false},
#     {:event_id=>321, :appointment=>401, :accounted=>false}]]
```

#### Explaining the slicing condition

An element is moved into a new group / array if:

- the previous appointment is false (`a == false`)
- the current appointment is false (`b == false`)
- the previous appointment is not the successor of the current appointment (`a.succ != b`)

Otherwise, i.e. both appointments are not `false` (I assume that appointments are either `false` or integers) and the previous appointment *is* the successor of the current one, they are kept in the same array.

Finding groups with 3 or more items is now trivial:

```
groups.select { |g| g.size >= 3 }

#=> [[{:event_id=>314, :appointment=>396, :accounted=>false},
#     {:event_id=>315, :appointment=>397, :accounted=>false},
#     {:event_id=>316, :appointment=>398, :accounted=>false}]]
```

Comment: Doh, sorry. I love it even more now.

Comment: This is pretty shiny. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
arr, arr1 = [], []
my_data.each do |e|
    arr << e if e[:appointment] != false
    arr = [] if e[:appointment] == false
    if arr.count == 3
       arr1 += arr
       arr = []
    end
end

2.1.2 :084 > arr1
 => [{:event_id=>314, :appointment=>396, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>315, :appointment=>397, :accounted=>false}, {:event_id=>316, :appointment=>398, :accounted=>false}]
```

Comment: This will find just the first 3-consecutive appointment group.

Answer (score 0):

This is my (agricultural) take on it.  I'm gonna experiment with some of the other solutions too..

```
def remaining_event_apps_consecutive(n)             
        result = []
        consec =[]
        @eas.each do |ea|           
            if ea[:appointment] != false && ea[:accounted] ==false                          
                consec << ea                
            else                
                consec = [] 
            end
            if consec.size == n             
                result << consec
                consec = []
            end
        end
        result
    end
```